# AJAX Script Failing to POST form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a Flask API that I've tested successfully with Postman that receives JSON data and commits it to a database. I am failing to do so with my HTML / JS from a browser however.

Bear with me as I'm just learning JS / jQuery.

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/submitworkorder', methods=['POST'])
def submitworkorder():
    form = SubmitWorkorderForm.from_json(request.json)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        customer = form.customer.data
        return jsonify({'customer' : customer })
    else:
        for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    error_data = (u"Error in the %s field - %s" % (getattr(form, field).label.text, error), 'error')
    return jsonify({'error' : error_data})
```

My JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : '/submitworkorder',
        data : $('form').serialize()
    })

    .done(function(data) {

        if (data.error) {
            $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
            $('#successAlert').hide();
        }
        else {
                $('#successAlert').text(data.customer + 'successfully created.').show();
                $('#errorAlert').hide();
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();

}); 

});
```

My HTML / Form:

```
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <form class="form-inline">
         {{ form.customer }}
         {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

      <input type="submit" value="go"/>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Console - The error you're seeing here is the returned data from my WTForms validation errors.
`Object {error: Array(2)}
error:Array(2)0:
"Error in the customer field - This field is required."
1:"error"length:2`

Comment: url should be enclosed by single quotes like this url : '/submitworkorder',  and missing comma at end of same line

Comment: check in your console.what errors it shows AND use success instead of done

Comment: Remember use always your console "F12" to debug.

Comment: Please post your console output here

Comment: @AkhilMenon - The console is completely empty on both the dev terminal and Chrome developer tools, except for some a favicon 404. I don't have one set. Even after attempting to post data.

Comment: did you included jquery link ?

Comment: I've cut down my application to one field, and am still getting errors even after trying both code answers below. I'm fairly sure the main problem is the data from the form isn't getting passed to the AJAX call. I've updated my HTML on the OP for review as well as added the console output.

Comment: Issue resolved, answer [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138994/wtforms-json-not-receiving-form-data). Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138994/wtforms-json-not-receiving-form-data), thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138994/wtforms-json-not-receiving-form-data). Basically there was some old documentation floating around that caused me to use JSON extensions for Flask-WTForms, however now WTForms supports it.

Answer (score 0):

1) url should be enclosed by single quotes like this

```
url : '/submitworkorder',
```

2) And missing comma at end of same line

3) Add dataType

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. Updated OP with console output.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType: "json"

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url : "/submitworkorder",
        data : $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
                   if (data.error) {
    $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
    $('#successAlert').hide();
}
else {
        $('#successAlert').text(data.customer + 'successfully created.').show();
        $('#errorAlert').hide();
}
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. Updated OP with console output.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url : "/submitworkorder",
            data : $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
               alert("Got success response")
               console.log(data) 
               $('#successAlert').text(data.customer + 'successfully created.').show();
               $('#errorAlert').hide();
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("Got error response")
                console.log(data)
                $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
                $('#successAlert').hide();
            }

      });
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. Updated OP with console output.

Comment: As you can see the error message in console output, its clear that there is no problem in the ajax. You should check the data of the form before passing to ajax.

Comment: Check  the output of form data that you are passing to ajax i.e console.log("form Data:", $('form').serialize())

Comment: Okay I put that line in before the ajax runs and the console showed `form Data: customer=test%20name` when I posted the form, which looks correct?