# WTForms-JSON not receiving form data

Tags: javascript, json, flask, flask-wtforms

[WTForms-JSON docs here.](https://wtforms-json.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

This has been a bug from hell I cannot wrap my head around.

I have a simple API handler that works perfectly fine from Postman JSON POSTs.

However when I plug the data into a web form the JSON is all empty. For example:

```
162.249.161.234 - - [23/May/2017 10:52:55] "POST /submitworkorder HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'customer': None}
```

My Flask is as follows:

```
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        form = SubmitWorkorderForm.from_json(request.json)
        print form.data
        return render_template('submitworkorder.html', form = form)

    @app.route('/submitworkorder', methods=['POST'])
    def submitworkorder():
        form = SubmitWorkorderForm.from_json(request.json)
        print form.data
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            customer = form.customer.data
            return jsonify({'customer' : customer })
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline">
     {{ form.customer }}
     {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

  <input type="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
<br>
<div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Lastly my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     console.log("form Data:", $('form').serialize())
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url : "/submitworkorder",
            data : $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                       if (data.error) {
        $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
        $('#successAlert').hide();
    }
    else {
            $('#successAlert').text(data.customer + 'successfully created.').show();
    $('#errorAlert').hide();
    }
            }
        });

    });
```

I have been working on this for the better part of 8 hours with no progress at all. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by some old documentation floating around. WTForms has built in support for handling serialized JSON now, **you don't** need the `from_json` or the `request.json` anymore.

Simply import and instantiate your form as you would.

Fixed code as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
    def index():
    form = SubmitWorkorderForm.from_json()
    print form.data
    return render_template('submitworkorder.html', form = form)
```